# Word VBA: recursive word search and work count

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to create a Word macro VBA to do the following:

1. for the active Word document
2. find the name “Bob” and count how many times “this is new” is associated to Bob (recursion search and count)
3. For example. Bob = 2, Matthew = 1, Mark = 0

---

Report – JP

PQR – Bob, Mark
·   Some text

Report – SH

JKL – Bob, Mark
·   Some text

GHI – Bob
·   This is new.
·   More text

Report – JM

MNO – Bob, Mark
·   Some text

DEF – Bob
·   This is new.
·   More text

ABC – Matthew
·   This is new.
·   More text

Report – BB

PQR – Bob, Mark
·   Some text

---

I believe that my attempt using this code is not correct. Any help?

```
        sResponse = "is new"
        iCount = 0
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False            
        With Selection
            .HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
            With .Find
                .ClearFormatting
                .Text = sResponse
                ' Loop until Word can no longer
                ' find the search string and
                ' count each instance
                Do While .Execute
                    iCount = iCount + 1
                    Selection.MoveRight
                Loop
              End With
              MsgBox sResponse & " appears " & iCount & " times
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A part of your stated original problem was that you wanted to list ALL of the names, including names that NEVER show up as lines with the phrase "This is new". So the code must build a `Dictionary` of names and keep track of each name and its count as all the lines are scanned. (See [this site](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/) for good information on dictionaries.)

There are a couple of "gotchas" in the ultimate solution, including allowing for names with accented characters (e.g. José) and names with spaces (e.g. "Bob Smith"). So I created a special "trim" function to scan each name and make sure the string is really just the name.

***Assumptions:***

1. Lines that DO NOT begin with "Report" are the lines that have names
2. The words separated by commas after the dash character are the names
3. The list of names ends when you find the special "separator" character

Here is the example code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CountPhrase()
    '--- define the dash and separator characters/strings - may be special codes
    Dim dash As String
    Dim separator As String
    Dim phrase As String
    dash = "–"               'this is not a keyboard dash
    separator = "·"          'this is not a keyboard period
    phrase = "This is new"
    
    Dim nameCount As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set nameCount = New Scripting.Dictionary
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To ThisDocument.Sentences.Count
        '--- locate the beginning of the names lines (that DO NOT have start with "Report")
        If Not (ThisDocument.Sentences(i) Like "Report*") Then
            '--- pick out the names for this report
            Dim dashPosition As Long
            Dim separatorPosition As Long
            dashPosition = InStr(1, ThisDocument.Sentences(i), dash, vbTextCompare)
            separatorPosition = InStr(1, ThisDocument.Sentences(i), separator, vbTextCompare)
            
            Dim names() As String
            names = Split(Mid$(ThisDocument.Sentences(i), _
                               dashPosition + 1, _
                               separatorPosition - dashPosition), ",")
            
            '--- now check if the phrase exists in this sentence or not
            Dim phrasePosition As Long
            phrasePosition = InStr(1, ThisDocument.Sentences(i), phrase, vbTextCompare)
            
            '--- add names to the dictionary if they don't exist, and increment
            '    the name count if the phrase exists in this sentence
            Dim name As Variant
            For Each name In names
                Dim thisName As String
                thisName = SpecialTrim$(name)
                If Len(thisName) > 0 Then
                    If nameCount.Exists(thisName) Then
                        If phrasePosition > 0 Then
                            nameCount(thisName) = nameCount(thisName) + 1
                        End If
                    Else
                        If phrasePosition > 0 Then
                            nameCount.Add thisName, 1
                        Else
                            nameCount.Add thisName, 0
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next name
        End If
    Next i
    
    '--- show your work
    Dim popUpMsg As String
    popUpMsg = "Frequency Report:"
    For Each name In nameCount.Keys
        popUpMsg = popUpMsg & vbCrLf & name & _
                   ": count = " & nameCount(name)
    Next name
    MsgBox popUpMsg, vbInformation + vbOKOnly
End Sub

Function SpecialTrim(ByVal inString As String) As String
    '--- this function can be tricky, because you have to allow
    '    for characters with accents and you must allow for names
    '    with spaces (e.g., "Bob Smith")
    '--- trim from the left until the first allowable letter
    Dim keepString As String
    Dim thisLetter As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(inString)
        thisLetter = Mid$(inString, i, 1)
        If LetterIsAllowed(thisLetter) Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    
    '-- special case: if ALL of the letters are not allowed, return
    '                 an empty string
    If i = Len(inString) Then
        SpecialTrim = vbNullString
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    '--- now transfer allowable characters to the keeper
    '    we're done when we reach the first unallowable letter (or the end)
    For i = i To Len(inString)
        thisLetter = Mid$(inString, i, 1)
        If LetterIsAllowed(thisLetter) Then
            keepString = keepString & thisLetter
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    SpecialTrim = Trim$(keepString)
End Function

Function LetterIsAllowed(ByVal inString As String) As Boolean
    '--- inString is expected to be a single character
    '    NOTE: a space " " is allowed in the middle, so the caller must
    '          Trim the returned string
    Const LETTERS = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" & _
                    "àáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöùúûüýÿŠŽšžŸÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝ"
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(LETTERS)
        If inString = Mid$(LETTERS, i, 1) Then
            LetterIsAllowed = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    LetterIsAllowed = False
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you PeterT for your time. I enabled the reference following the indicated link. However, I do not see where the Dictionary file stored. Is there something I am missing?
To use the Dictionary you need to first add the reference.

Select Tools->References from the Visual Basic menu.
Find Microsoft Scripting Runtime in the list and place a check in the box beside it.

Comment: There is no dictionary "file" at all. The `Dictionary` is an object that lets you manage data (the "count") associated with a key (the "name") -- this happens all in memory. You are correct that placing a checkmark next to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime will give enable your code to use the `Dictionary`. After you enable this library, the code in my example above should run with no issues. Are you receiving an error?

Comment: hi PeterT, I added the macro with 2 Functions and 1 Subroutine on Word 365 and executed CountPhrase. No popup message appears. Is a file saved somehere on my computer?

Comment: Please see the updated code above that will generate a popup `MsgBox` to show your results.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim StrNm As String, StrOut As String, i As Long
StrOut = "Bob = 0, " & _
  "Matthew = 0, " & _
  "Mark = 0, "
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "<[! ]@ · This is new"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute
    If .Text = "" Then Exit Do
    StrNm = Split(.Text, " ")(0)
    If InStr(StrOut, StrNm) > 0 Then
      i = Split(Split(StrOut, StrNm & " = ")(1), ", ")(0)
      StrOut = Replace(StrOut, StrNm & " = " & i, StrNm & " = " & i + 1)
    Else
      StrOut = StrOut & StrNm & " = " & 1 & ", "
    End If
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Frequency Report:" & StrOut
End Sub
```

If you've missed any names with 'This is new', the code above will simply add them to the pre-defined StrOut list.

Comment: Thank you for your time macropod. When I run this macro in Word, I get: Bob: 0, Matthew: 0, Mark: 0 This:3. I was looking for a count to match this: Bob = 2, Matthew = 1, Mark = 0

Comment: When I run the code against the data you posted, I get «Frequency Report:/Bob: 2/Matthew: 1/Mark: 0» There is no 'This:3'. Evidently, either you messed up your implementation or the data are not as you described. I've modified the code to output your preferred format, which your post only gave as an example.

Comment: Hi, yes this macro worked. I noticed that my Word document had the line "GHI – Bob · This is new. · More text" split on 2 lines. When I copied this text to stack overlfow, it merged these 2 lines into 1 line.